# Invisible NSView is asked to draw

Tags: swift, macos, draw, nsview

Is it normal when you add a subview which is not visible in the window, that it's draw(_:) method is called? 
So, the subview's frame lays outside of the .visibleRect of the window's .contentView.

I thought that drawing was done "as needed", and invisible doesn't seem to be needed to me.

A weird thing is that when the width or the height of the subview is higher than 256, then the draw(_:) method is not called.

I did found out that the "responsive scrolling" mechanism can cause more draw(_:) calls to invisible views. However, with responsive scrolling the NSView.prepareContent(in:) method is used.
The documentation of this method says:

*"During responsive scrolling, AppKit calls this method before asking your view to draw any content in the overdraw region."*

In my case this prepareContent(in:) method is not called, so responsive scrolling doesn't seem to be the cause.

Some other documentation says:

*"The first time a view appears in a window, the rectangle matches the bounds of the view and the view draws all of its content. Subsequently, the view draws itself only when necessary and draws only that part of itself that has changed."*

In my case the call to the draw(_:) method is passed a dirtyRect for the whole content.

So the call to draw(_:) looks like a normal first call but the 256 and being invisible make it unclear to me.

Hope to hear your thoughts.

This is my swift example code:

```
class FirstView: NSView {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)

        // Add the invisible subview.
        // A width or height of 257 will not be drawed.
        let subview = SecondView(frame: NSRect(x: 12345, y: 0, width: 256, height: 256))
        self.addSubview(subview)
    }

    override func prepareContent(in rect: NSRect) {

        print("FirstView.prepareContent()")

        super.prepareContent(in: rect)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        print("FirstView.draw() \(dirtyRect)")

        // White background.
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        NSColor.white.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}

class SecondView: NSView {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override func prepareContent(in rect: NSRect) {

        print("SecondView.prepareContent()")

        super.prepareContent(in: rect)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        print("SecondView.draw() \(dirtyRect)")

        // Blue background.
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        NSColor.blue.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't supposed to call print in a NSView subclass.

Comment: It's only for test purposes, to get a feel of what happens underneath. Do you know an alternative for print()?